# Large number of associated product(5000) of a configurable product showing blank page

Tags: configurable-product, products, simple-product

I have created a Configurable product and added about 5000 simple products to it, but now if I try to view the product on the front end or in the Admin I just get a blank Page? can anybody point me in the right direction on our to correct this, looks like a memory issue.

I can see all the Simple products in the admin

Comment: how many varience is there? This is not feasible from customer point of view?

Comment: 5000 variations of one product?

Answer (score 2):

> looks like a memory issue

Yeah, probably, and additionally you will get client side performance issues in the frontend. 5000 simple products in one configurable product is way too much for Magento.

I'll quote myself from a recent [forum thread](https://community.magento.com/t5/Hosting-Performance/Configurable-Product-Limitations/m-p/60368#M1289):

> While there is no enforced limit, Magento does not handle big numbers
> of associated products efficiently. For example the price data for
> each associated product is loaded into one big JavaScript object
> (JSON). And database queries on the product page are another
> bottleneck, especially if you use the swatches feature.
>
> We have a
> similar situation but with even higher numbers and are currently
> working on our own lightweight configurable product type.
>
> #### The rough concept:
>
> - data for associated products is stored as flat data structure (probably a NoSQL storage): configurable attributes, price rules, skus
>   (add more if needed)
> - optimize data in frontend to not pregenerate data for each combination (for example calculate price on the fly)
> - when a product is ordered, a real simple product based on the selection is created temporarily. This allows us to use all sales
>   features without code changes
>
> This is just to give you an idea that for a use case like yours you
> will need a customized solution.

Comment: how did you do such customization? Could you please help me with this? I'm getting same issue in Magento 2.3.5 with having 1100 associate products showing me blank page.

Answer (score 2):

```
memory issue
```

Set php.ini or .htaccess file `post_max_size 100M` , `max_input_vars 5000` and remove cache..

Comment: Increasing the memory is not recommended since a configurable product is not intended to have this many variations.