# Can it handle products with up to 100,000 variations

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute

We are building a site for a client in WooCommerce and have come stuck on the capability (not being there)

We have some products that have up to 100,000 different variations, also with a base price and click rate

Can Magento handle this amount of variations?

Answer (score 0):

100,000 variations products in one configurable product is way too much for Magento.

[Fabian Schmengler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/243/fabian-schmengler) say on a [forum thread on community.magento.com](https://community.magento.com/t5/Hosting-Performance/Configurable-Product-Limitations/m-p/60368#M1289):

> While there is no enforced limit, Magento does not handle big numbers
> of associated products efficiently. For example the price data for
> each associated product is loaded into one big JavaScript object
> (JSON). And database queries on the product page are another
> bottleneck, especially if you use the swatches feature.
>
> We have a
> similar situation but with even higher numbers and are currently
> working on our own lightweight configurable product type.
>
> #### The rough concept:
>
> - data for associated products is stored as flat data structure (probably a NoSQL storage): configurable attributes, price rules, skus
>   (add more if needed)
> - optimize data in frontend to not pregenerate data for each combination (for example calculate price on the fly)
> - when a product is ordered, a real simple product based on the selection is created temporarily. This allows us to use all sales
>   features without code changes
>
> This is just to give you an idea that for a use case like yours you
> will need a customized solution.

*source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160236/24845*